# Is there a way to organize my drawables in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, directory-structure, android-vectordrawable

Since I can't have directories in my `res/drawable` directory, how can I  organize my drawable folders like buttons, icons, images, bg_images, etc.

How to have an organized folders for the drawable. I want to have a organizes directory because later on I will have many drawable as my project expand.